# Making sure that chapter headings appear at top of page with least gap

Tags: spacing, chapters, line-spacing, gap

I was told by my supervisor to insert this:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%This puts chapter titles right at the top and changes line spacing
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{10pt}{\Huge}   
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-70pt}{15pt}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
```

At the top of my document to essentially make my chapter titles appear right at the top of every page of a new chapter.

You can run this to see what it does:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}% Not sure what this is for
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}% For quotes in chapters
\usepackage{epigraph}% This is for named paragraphs
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}% This is for aligned equations
\usepackage{listings}%This is for code listings
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}

\lstset{frame=tb,
  language=Java,
  aboveskip=3mm,
  belowskip=3mm,
  showstringspaces=false,
  columns=flexible,
  basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
  numbers=none,
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
  stringstyle=\color{mauve},
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  tabsize=3
}
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\usepackage{algpseudocode}%http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
% \usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}
\algrenewcommand\textproc{}% Used to be \textsc
\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}
\usepackage{calc} % for \widthof
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicensure{%
  \makebox[\widthof{\textbf{Require:}}][l]{\textbf{Ensure:}}} 
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%This puts chapter titles right at the top and changes line spacing
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{10pt}{\Huge}   
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-70pt}{15pt}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Implementation of Approach}\label{implementation}

lorem ipsum

\end{document}
```

You can see that the result is:

[image]

Which means that it got rid of my chapter heading `Implementation of Approach` and also still kept a huge gap between the chapter title and the next line of text (`lorem ipsum`).

What am I missing here and what can I do to solve those two issues above?

Comment: I suggest that you make a _minimal_ example. For example, the '\lstset' probably has nothing to do with your problem, so take it away. Continue to comment out part by part until your problem disappears. Then update your question with what is left, pointing åt the problematik part/line. That way it will be much easier for people to focus on the actual problem, and to be able to help you in a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have specified the *explicit* option to the titlesec package.  This means that you must specify exactly where the argument passed to the sectioning command (`\chapter` in your case) should go by placing `#1` in the *before-code* parameter of `\titleformat`.  If I make the following change to your macro invocation, it addresses both your issues:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%This puts chapter titles right at the top and changes line spacing
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{10pt}{\Huge #1}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}% Not sure what this is for
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}% For quotes in chapters
\usepackage{epigraph}% This is for named paragraphs
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}% This is for aligned equations
\usepackage{listings}%This is for code listings
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}

\lstset{frame=tb,
  language=Java,
  aboveskip=3mm,
  belowskip=3mm,
  showstringspaces=false,
  columns=flexible,
  basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
  numbers=none,
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
  stringstyle=\color{mauve},
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  tabsize=3
}
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\usepackage{algpseudocode}%http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
% \usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}
\algrenewcommand\textproc{}% Used to be \textsc
\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}
\usepackage{calc} % for \widthof
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicensure{%
  \makebox[\widthof{\textbf{Require:}}][l]{\textbf{Ensure:}}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%This puts chapter titles right at the top and changes line spacing
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{10pt}{\Huge #1}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-70pt}{15pt}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Implementation of Approach}\label{implementation}

lorem ipsum

\end{document}
```